# Can't access complete JSON string in handlebars using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mongodb, express

I am developing client side programming in ExpressJS using handlebars. I have to get a JSON from my router (mongoDB) to jQuery variables. But I can't get it. The JSON shows the error, after line breaks. But I can get from AJAX. Here the code and the error.

Code

```
var locationData = '{{location}}';

var lctdata = jQuery.parseJSON(locationData);

$.each(lctdata, function (lctkey, lctvalue) {
    alert(lctvalue.name);
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

                        var locationData = '{ _id: 5e967a286c55800d3c301308,
  name: &#x27;Store&#x27;,
  level: &#x27;0&#x27;,
  haschild: &#x27;1&#x27;,
  description: &#x27;All Stores&#x27;,
  created_date: &#x27;2020-04-15:08:36:16&#x27;,
  __v: 0 },{ _id: 5e967a5a6c55800d3c301309,
  name: &#x27;RS Puram Branch&#x27;,
  parent: &#x27;Store&#x27;,
  level: &#x27;1&#x27;,
  haschild: &#x27;0&#x27;,
  description:
   &#x27;Store is located in RS PURAM. One of the highly powerful store in the city&#x27;,
  created_date: &#x27;2020-04-15:08:37:06&#x27;,
  __v: 0 }';

                    var lctdata = jQuery.parseJSON(locationData);
                    $.each(lctdata, function (lctkey, lctvalue) {
                        alert(lctvalue.name);
                    });
```

The error shows in the first line itself as unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{{{location}}}` to keep handlebars from HTML escaping your JSON. Note the three braces instead of two. See https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping

You also don't need to wrap your (invalid) JSON in quotes. Since it's invalid JSON, `JSON.parse` won't parse it correctly, but the JS parser will correctly parse it since it is a valid object initializer in JavaScript.

When you wrap your JSON-like string in quotes, they are clashing with the single quotes inside your JSON-like string. For example, `var c = '{a: 'hello'}'`

```
// Additional tip: no jQuery required.
var locationData = {{{location}};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(locationData)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Still shows same error in console after replacing this code.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: // Additional tip: no jQuery required.
      var locationData = '{ _id: 5e967a286c55800d3c301308,
  name: 'Store',
  level: '0',
  haschild: '1',
  description: 'All Stores',
  created_date: '2020-04-15:08:36:16',
  __v: 0 },{ _id: 5e967a5a6c55800d3c301309,
  name: 'RS Puram Branch',
  parent: 'Store',
  level: '1',
  haschild: '0',
  description:
   'Store is located in RS PURAM. One of the highly powerful store in the city',
  created_date: '2020-04-15:08:37:06',
  __v: 0 }';
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(locationData)) {
console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

Comment: It seems you are wrapping your (invalid) JSON with quotes even though I said you shouldn't? Your variable `location` does not look like valid JSON since it doesn't quote properties with double quotes and it uses single quotes for string. Having said that, if you do what I suggested, without the quotes around `{{{location}}}`, it would work because `location` does contain a valid object initializer in JS even it if it's not correct JSON.

Comment: No. I doesn't wrap with quotes. The code is just placed as you given. 
var locationData = {{{location}}};

Comment: That is not what you typed on your comment `var locationData = '{ _id: 5e967a286c55800d3c301308, name: 'Store'`, notice the `'` before the `{`

Comment: Okay. Let me check.

Comment: I have checked it. I think mongodb doesn't return a Valid JSON string.

Comment: I have found the alternative option for that. Thanks Juan Mendes. 

{{#each location}} works inside jquery also.

Thanks for the reply.